# Rolling window datasets in Python problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Hi I am very new to Python and would really appreciate if someone can help me with my problem:

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
Date        rf1     rf2      rf3.....rf15
01-01-2008  FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
02-01-2008  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
03-01-2008  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
04-01-2008  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE     TRUE
```

I wanted to create 250 days period using the dates column in the data frame with a rolling period of 20 days. For ex, my first period would start on `01-01-2008` to +250 days, my second period would start on `20-01-2008` to +250 days and so forth.

I want two conditions to be satisfied:

1. I need to select those 250 days periods in which my `TRUE` count in a column <24
2. In the 250 days window that I have created my columns should be `FALSE` for straight 90 days on 1 day rolling

I have the below code, but somehow not able to figure out how to get my two conditions right.

```
    import pandas as pd
result = df.rolling(250, on='Date').sum().dropna().rename(
    columns={'Date': 'End'}).assign(Start=df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(249, 'D'))



# reorder columns
result = result.reindex(columns=['Start', 'End', 'rf1', 'rf2','rf3','rf4','rf5','rf6','rf7','rf8','rf9','rf10','rf11','rf12','rf13','rf14','rf15'])



# resample on every 20th day
result=result.resample('20D', on='Start').first().reset_index(drop=True)
```

This code gives me the 250 days window, but I am not sure how to satisfy my two conditions on this data frame! Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: For condition 1 - do you care which column is true? Should it be any of them? A specific one? Same question for condition 2.

Comment: Hi, any column in my 250 day window!

Comment: And one additional question - do you already have data and you're looking for find dates (windows) that meet these criteria or are you looking to randomly (?) generate it?

Comment: I have data stored in dataframe called df, which has 'dates' column on which I am looking to generate these 250 days periods

Comment: "Generate" - as in random data?

Comment: yes thats correct